# How can I deploy my ember cli website to GoDaddy?

Tags: ember.js, web-deployment, ember-cli

I'm new to web deployment. Can anyone tell / show me the steps I have to make to deploy my ember cli app to GoDaddy? If in anyway GoDaddy does not support ember cli app, is there a way like some sort of like the java files that can be compiled or something like that in ember to be able to deploy it in any hosting site? If so, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 7):

Ember-CLI app can be deployed to any hosting site as the web server only has to serve static content, generated by executing

```
ember build --environment=production
```

This command packages all required files for the application into `/dist` folder.

From there, all you need to do is to copy the contents of the `/dist` folder to a web server and configure it to serve the contents of this folder.

For browser history to work properly, you should also setup web server to serve all routes with index.html file (see example for [Apache server](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/apache-rewrite-rule-for-html5-browser-history-url-bookmarkability/1013))

Comment: I did the `ember build --environment=production` and the files were generated in the `dist` folder. I uploaded all the files included under that directory to the host but the webpage isn't looking what it's supposed to be. Just a dull webpage.

Comment: I think this is the issue I am having but I am hosting with GoDaddy and am not on Apache. Any idea how I can modify my host to allow Ember to behave naturally?

Answer (score 3):

Run $ ember build --environment=production
This will compile a production version of your app. Your server needs to be able to serve your index.html file. Beyond that there are no requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably also want gzip compression: https://medium.com/@bryan.hughes/how-to-enable-compression-on-godaddy-shared-linux-server-deflate-gzip-44f2ab58d0ad#.9yod714no
and this rewrite rule https://gist.github.com/dehuszar/68a18367f7e9fa6fb127 (found by searching https://www.google.com/search?q=ember+cli+where+to+put+.htaccess+file)

Added into `[your-app]/public/.htaccess`

```
# place in [your-app]/public so it gets compiled into the dist folder
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks

  RewriteEngine On

  # If you get 404 error, uncomment and change the line below.
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

<files *.html>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.svg>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

I didn't worry about gziping the index.html. See the article on medium.com for that.

I also use ember-cli-deploy with ember-cli-deploy-build and ember-cli-deploy-ftp, but not ember-cli-deploy-gzip at this time. I also had to uninstall ember-cli-sri because of a strange error in the console about some SHA integrity hash check on my js and css files. At first ember-cli-favicon worked to generate my initial favicons, but then stopped working and I had to uninstall it. These tools are pretty easy to setup, but I'll let you navigate your way through setting them up, in case the docs change.